# Pig: Splitting large large file into multiple smaller files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need to split the output part file, generated by another Pig script, and generate groups each containing 1000 lines. These groups will be posted to a webservice for further processing. There is no relation between data so I cannot group the data on a specific field.

How can I do this in Pig?

Answer (score 4):

If the split is not related to the data why even use Pig or MapReduce at all? As an alternative you could just use the standard split program to split your data, if I didn't misunderstand. For example:

```
cat part-* | split -d -l 1000 - result-
```